# R function for repeat value on different lines

Tags: r, repeat

I have a dataframe on which there are several rows for the same individual, I have a value that appears only on the first row and I would like to repeat it on all the rows of the same individual. I work on r and I'm a beginner, so I have no idea how to do it.
Here is an example of what I would like :

```
ID     Status 
1      0
1
1
2      1
2
```

I would like to repeat all the status 0's on the subject lines 1 and all the status 1's on the subject lines

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: sorry i forgot to say hello

Comment: 1) welcome to SO, 2) you can edit your question directly, 3) look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and check out R's `dput()` function

Answer (score 0):

If your data look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    ID  = c(1,1,1,2,2), 
    Status = c(0, NA, NA, 1, NA))
```

You can pick the value from the first row for each ID.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Status = Status[1])


# A tibble: 5 × 2
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Status
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1      0
2     1      0
3     1      0
4     2      1
5     2      1
>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but unfortunately it doesn't work, it only gives me 0's and it doesn't take into account the change of subject. I think it's because my ID is a factor.
But I have subjects that have things like "3-2" etc as their ID, and if I convert it to numeric it changes my ID

Comment: If you provide your data and code, I can test it on my side.

Comment: how can I give you my data ?

Comment: As long as your ID is unique for each subject, it should not be matter. You may need to inspect your data first, make sure the values are in the first row for each subject. If not, we can try other solutions.

Comment: yes the values are in the first line for all subjects

Comment: Example data could be helpful for identifying the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to show you the data, but it looks like what I put in the first post

Comment: I just closed all my r codes and restarted everything and it works fine! Thank you very much for taking the time to help me

Answer (score 0):

```
ID                Status        Sexe       HEMOGLOBIN
1                  1              2             14,8
1                  NA             NA            12,6
1                  NA             NA            12,9
1                  NA             NA            13,3
1                  NA             NA            13
1                  NA             NA            12,7
1                  NA             NA            12,9
1                  NA             NA            13
1-2                0              1             14,9
1-3                0              1             17,2
1-3                NA             NA            16,6
1-3                NA             NA            16,7
```

the data is like this, on the first lines I have the socio-demographic characteristics and on the others I have measurements of haemoglobin levels over different periods
@Zhiqiang Wang